# Schengen short term visa fingerprint

Tags: schengen-visas

If the fingerprints have been taken in German embassay Islamabad for Schengen Visa, After how long time will the finger prints disappear in Schengen area/Europe??

Answer (score 4):

Data is kept in the Visa Information System (VIS) for five years. This retention period starts from the expiry date of the issued visa, the date a negative decision is taken or the date a decision to modify an issued visa is taken. https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en